# setting the userAgent via selenium is throwing exception

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have recently updated my selenium from 2.19.0 to 2.31.0. I am having problems while setting the userAgent for testing purposes. Here is the code:

```
void testMessage() {
    verifySomething(this.driver, "iPhone");
}

void verifySomething(WebDriver driver, String userAgent) {
    String script = null;
    if (driver instanceof HtmlUnitDriver) {
        script = "navigator.userAgent=" + "'" + userAgent + "';";
    }
    else {
        // something
    }
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script);
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> ======= EXCEPTION START ========

```
EcmaError: lineNumber=[1] column=[0] lineSource=[] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[injected script] message=[TypeError: Cannot set property [Navigator].userAgent that has only a getter to iPhone. (injected script#1)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot set property [Navigator].userAgent that has only a getter to iPhone. (injected script#1)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:663)
                at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:559)
                at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:525)
                at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:594)
                at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:569)
                at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:996)
                at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.executeScript(HtmlUnitDriver.java:466)
...
...
```

== CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==

```
  function () {
      navigator.userAgent = "iPhone";
  }

======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

I know that it is complaining about the setter. It use to work in selenium 2.19.0 but I guess they may have changed the property to read only.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set anything into the navigator.userAgent.

navigator.UserAgent is just informations about your current browser.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp

Comment: Agree but question is, if there is anyway to spoof the userAgent? My webpage supports different features depending upon what the userAgent is and I need to test this scenario by programmatically setting the userAgent.

Comment: I don't know, but take a look here [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html), you can simulate a phone.

Answer (score 0):

For FF use this (profile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", "your useragent")
everything needs to be set up from firefox profile.

Comment: Is there any equivalent for HtmlUnitDriver?

Comment: String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17"; // or your useragent                      BrowserVersion browser = new BrowserVersion(applicationName, applicationVersion, userAgent, browserVersionNumeric)